# How to put classes for javaagent in the classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath, javaagents

I am trying to develop a javaagent that would instrument code with help of asm-4. For now I'm stucked with a pretty basic problem, the classloader for the javaagent doesn't see asm dependencies and therefor fails. Do I have to provide a jar-with-dependencies (aka maven build plugin) which contains all the needed classes by the agent, or is there another way to add classes to the java agent?
Referencing the jar asm-all.jar directly in the classpath didn't help. 
Building jar-with-dependencies didn't help at first, because Premain-Class attribute couldn't be set with assembly plugin. 
Help is appreciated ;-)

Comment: ok, apparently I found the answer myself:
<manifestEntries>
  <Premain-Class>test.agent.MyAgent</Premain-Class>
</manifestEntries> <- the assembly plugin accepts same configuration options as the jar plugin

Comment: please write it as answer and accept it, so that the other users can see the answer of your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok, found it by experimenting. 
The dependent classes should be part of the jar, which can be created by maven assembly plugin, for example:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <index>true</index>
                <manifest>
                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                </manifest>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Premain-Class>test.agent.MyAgent</Premain-Class>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase>
                <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                    <!-- goals == mojos -->
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Use the jar as javaagent path and everything works fine.

Comment: The <Premain-Class>test.agent.MyAgent</Premain-Class> is important ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I followed this [blog post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things13/). 
Here is how I made it work, to get the size of objects.

/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: ar.com.docdigital.InstrumentationApp
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix: true
```

in your pom.xml (Note we reference custom MANIFEST)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>
                MANIFEST.MF
            </manifestFile>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>
                    ar.com.docdigital.App
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My Instrumentation Agent:

```
package ar.com.docdigital;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

/**
 *
 * @author juan.fernandez
 */
public class InstrumentationApp {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

My main App:

package ar.com.docdigital;

```
import static ar.com.docdigital.InstrumentationApp.getObjectSize;

/**
 *
 * @author juan.fernandez
 */
public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Size of CoprimeLong: " + getObjectSize(new CoprimesList.CoprimeLong(1L)));
        System.out.println("Size of Long: " + getObjectSize(new Long(1L)));

    }

}
```

Putting all together & CLI output:

```
$ mvn package
$ java -javaagent:target/primos-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -jar target/primos-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
  Size of CoprimeLong: 24
  Size of Long: 24
```

Comment: What if the agent and the project are in 2 separate jars ?

Answer (score 4):

I used maven-jar-plugin for my CustomAgent. I dont have any dependent modules/jars so using an assembly plugin is an overkill.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>are-agent</finalName>
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Premain-Class>are.agent.CustomAgent</Premain-Class>
                        <Can-Redefine-Classes>false</Can-Redefine-Classes>
                        <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can specify Class-Path in the Manifest.mf file in the MyAgent.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You should add Premain-Class entry to the manifest. I use gradle to build Java projects.

Add this to `gradle.build`

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Premain-Class": "com.training.agent.agentapp.SimplestAgent",
                "Can-Redefine-Classes": false,
                "Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix": false
        )
    }
}
```

And then you can run it

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar application.jar
```

[Mode details](https://ivanyu.me/blog/2017/11/04/java-agents-javassist-and-byte-buddy/)