# Issue running Java Agent

Tags: java, javaagents

I am trying to run a basic java agent.

I followed this:

[How to put classes for javaagent in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872642/how-to-put-classes-for-javaagent-in-the-classpath)

But I am getting these errors

```
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in target/demo.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Here is my agent

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class DriftDetector {

    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        System.out.println("Inside premain");
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

My manifest.mf (inside META-INF)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.example.demo.DriftDetector
```

and my main class

```
package com.example.demo;
import static com.example.demo.DriftDetector.getObjectSize;

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Size of Long: " + getObjectSize(new Long(1L)));
    }
}
```

Command to create jar

```
mvn package
```

command to run

```
java -javaagent:target/demo.jar -jar target/demo.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably error is in your  **manifest.mf**

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: DriftDetector

Tty like this its works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can view some javaagent examples from https://github.com/kananindzya/javaagent-example .

In "memory-counter" module you can find information in README.md how to build and run manual or with maven and idea.